# Python Multiprocessing Passing Variables To Function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to insert an class object, to Multiprocessing.Manager.dict() but I'm getting the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\Program Files\Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "X:\Program Files\Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "xxx", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "xxx", line 52, in main
    d[1] = conn
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "xxx", line 850, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line 243, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "XXX", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
**_pickle.UnpicklingError: state is not a dictionary**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

THE FOLLOWING ERROR CAUSED BECAUSE:

```
d = Manager().dict()

d[1] = conn

print(d[1])
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `conn` is apparently not a pickleable object, which is required for anything that gets transferred between processes.  We'd need to know more about the type of that object to say anything further.

Comment: Can you show enough code for a reproducible case?

Comment: My code is really long and clumsy.. My purpose is to transfer the connection object to Interactive Brokers if you know. If the item is not pickleable, what can I do?